# Ошибка в pygame: TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

> TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)

Coding: UTF-8:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
Impactmed = pygame.font.Font("fonts\\ImpactRegular\\ImpactRegular.ttf", 50)
Impactsmall = pygame.font.Font("fonts\\ImpactRegular\\ImpactRegular.ttf", 30)
Impactlarge = pygame.font.Font("fonts\\ImpactRegular\\ImpactRegular.ttf", 100)
size = [800, 600]
r_x = 0
r_y = 260
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
colours = {
'black' : (0, 0, 0),
'white' : (255, 255, 255),
'yellow' : (255, 255, 0),
'blue': (0, 0, 255),
'red' : (0, 255, 0)}
b_blockcrdnts = [550, r_y]
hero = {'rect' : pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours['black'],[r_x, r_y, 60, 50], 50)}
white1 = 255,255,255
blue1 = 0,0,255
hp = 0
r = 50
h = 50
dflt = [60, 50]
pygame.display.set_caption('1')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
def events():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_W:
                r_y += 10
                r_y -= 1
                r_y -= 1
                r_y -= 1
                r_y -= 1
                r_y -= 1
                r_y -= 1
                r_y -= 1
                r_y -= 1
                r_y -= 1
                r_y -= 1

            elif event.key == pygame.K_D:
                r_x += 1

            elif event.key == pygame.K_A:
                r_x -= 1

        else:
            print(event)

def mainmenu():
    m_m_c = 0
    while m_m_c == 0:
        for eventmain in pygame.event.get():
            if eventmain.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

            elif eventmain.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if eventmain.type == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    glav()

        maintxt1 = Impactmed.render(u'Нажми' + str('space') + str(u'чтобы начать'), blue1, white1)
        maintxt1rect = maintxt1.get_rect()
        maintxt1rect.center(333, 268)
        screen.blit(maintxt1, maintxt1rect)
        screen.fill(colours['white'])
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)

def draw():
    o_block = 0
    hero['rect']
    b_block = pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours['red'],[b_blcokcrdnts, 60, 50], 50)
    if hero['rect'] == b_blockcrdnts:
        hp = 1


    while o_block < 17:
        if o_block == 1:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours['yellow'],[0, 260, 60, 50], 50)
            o_block += 1

        elif o_block == 2:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours['yellow'],[50, 260, 60, 50], 50)
            o_block += 1

        elif o_block == 3:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours['yellow'],[100, 260, 60, 50], 50)
            o_block += 1

        elif o_block == 4:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours['yellow'],[150, 260, 60, ])
            o_block += 1

        elif o_block == 5:    
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours['yellow'],[200, 260, 60, 50], 50)
            o_block += 1

        elif o_block == 6:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours['yellow'],[250, 260, dflt], r)
            o_block += 1

        elif o_block == 7:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours['yellow'],[300, 260, dflt], r)
            o_block += 1

        elif o_block == 8:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours['yellow'],[350, 260, dflt], r)
            o_block += 1

        elif o_block == 9:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours['yellow'],[400, 260, dflt], r)
            o_block += 1

        elif o_block == 10:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours['yellow'],[400+h, 260, dflt], r)
            o_block += 1

        elif o_block == 11:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours['yellow'],[450+h, 260, dflt], r)
            o_block += 1

        elif o_block == 12:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours['yellow'],[500+h, 260, dflt], r)
            o_block += 1

        elif o_block == 13:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours['yellow'],[550+h, 260, dflt], r)
            o_block += 1

        elif o_block == 14:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours['yellow'],[600+h, 260, dflt], r)
            o_block += 1

        elif o_block == 15:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours['yellow'],[650+h, 260, dflt], r)
            o_block += 1

        elif o_block == 16:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours['yellow'],[700+h, 260, dflt], r)
            o_block += 1


def die():
    di = 0
    while di == 0:
        for eventdie in pygame.event.get():
            if eventdie.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

            elif eventdie.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_R:
                   hero['hp'] = 0


        dietxt = Impactlarge.render(u'Вы проиграли!', colours['white'], colours['black'])
        dietxt2 = Impactmed.render(u'Нажмите' + str('R') + str(u'Чтобы перезагрузить игру!'), white, colours['black'])
        dietxtrect = dietxt.get_rect()
        dietxtrect.center = (213, 223)
        dietxt2rect = dietxt2.get_rect()
        dietxt2rect.center = (367, 301)
        dietxt3 = Impactsmall.render(u'Также нажмите ' + str('ESC') + str(u'чтобы войти в главное меню!'), colours['white'], colours['black'])
        dietxt3rect = dietxt3.get_rect()
        dietxt3rect.center(357, 405)
        screen.blit(dietxt, dietxtrect)
        screen.blit(dietxt2, dietxt2rect)
        screen.blit(dietxt3, dietxt3rect)
        screen.fill(colours['black'])
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)

def glav():            
    while True:
        if hp == 1:
            die()

        elif hp == 0:
            events()
            draw()

        pygame.display.flip()
        screen.fill(colours['white'])
        clock.tick(30)
```

> mainmenu()

На строке 67.

Comment: Покажите строку 67 на которой ошибка. Жалуется, что вы не число передали

Comment: maintxt1 = Impactmed.render(u'Нажми' + str('space') + str(u'чтобы начать'), blue1, white1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте про функцию `Impactmed.render(a, b, c)`. У вас проблемы с аргументами b и c. Вы передаете кортеж

```
white1 = 255,255,255
blue1 = 0,0,255
```

хотя функция ожидает увидеть int. Возможно, цвет стоит задавать как число, например **0xFFFFFF**.

Answer (score 1):

Oшибка говорит, что вы передаёте список (кортеж), а не аргументы.
Ваша 67 строка:

```
maintxt1 = Impactmed.render(u'Нажми' + str('space') + str(u'чтобы начать'), blue1, white1)

white1 = 255,255,255 #это значения строк 20 и 21
blue1 = 0,0,255
```

Вам нужно указывать данные переменные как *blue1 и *white1